# Copying native DLL to different locations depending on Unity build options

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, windows-10

In order to unload and load native plugins easily in Unity, I am currently using `LoadLibrary(DllPath)`. The problem with this is that since it is searching the given path, for UnityEditor it looks at the `root` folder (beside `Assets`), and for the built `play.exe`, it is looking in the same directory as the `play.exe`.

So to make this process more efficient, I want to be able to automatically copy the .dll into `play_data\plugins` folder when it is being built into a `play.exe`. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the UnityAPI [OnPostprocessBuildAPI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html) in script to copy the dlls to your exe location.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEditor.Callbacks;

    public class MyBuildPostprocessor 
    {
        [PostProcessBuildAttribute(1)]
        public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget target, string pathToBuiltProject) 
        {
            Debug.Log( pathToBuiltProject );
            File.Copy("Oringal File",pathToBuiltProject + "\play_data\plugins\" + Your dll);
        }
    }
```

The option "**pathToBuiltProject**" will give you your executable location. You can navigate to "play_data\plugins" using **pathToBuiltProject**. I use this API to move custom runtime files.

---

I also realized this you said you are loading from `LoadLibrary(DllPath)`. So does this mean you have not included the dll's in the Plugin folder in assets? Because the dlls in Plugin folders inside the Unity project are added in "yourprogramName_data\Plugins" after compiling. If so then you might want to add keep the dll in plugins folder and let Unity automatically do it for you. And if you have dlls which you dynamically needed to added to plugins folder after completion of build you can use the first method.

Comment: Thank you, as you said since Unity automatically adds plugins from the Plugins folder, simply putting the file there worked out for me. Now I need to figure out how to use the .dll inside yourprogramName_data\Plugins when using the .exe.